# React Library: Doesn't fully apply styles

Tags: css, reactjs

Good morning, good afternoon and good evening!

I just installed REACT.

```
  <nav class="relative container mx-auto bg-red-500">
    Hello
  </nav>
```

This is a piece of code I wrote as a first try. It does seem to work but just as I wanted to enter "p-6" to get a padding, it didn't translate it. Same problem when I want to change the "margin" to only right for example (mr-6) -> Nothing happens

What am I doing wrong? It should be installed right, if not I coulnd't do the first code I sent in

Comment: So, you are using `tailwind CSS` then check all configurations files that you have installed  before `tailwind CSS`, refer to this [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that. I just installed it as shown on their DOCS website -> https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: I think I figuiried it out. In the TERMINAL I have to paste (npm run watch) which is a small skript i have. After this the changes are seen. I run it with LIVE SERVER in VSCode and thought that would be it. But now i have to somehow run this command all the time

Comment: As you said, that is actually can work with `Tailwind CLI` If you don't mind can I give a demo example to get better understanding to you?

Comment: Yes, send something

Comment: Okay after working a little bit more the problem is really just: After each change I need to put "npm run watch" in the terminal. Then the effects take changes. Is there a way to automate this

Comment: Hi, @Tim Bordasch you can see my answer and please mess around with the demo to get better grasp of using tailwind CSS

Answer (score 0):

While using `tailwind CSS`, you need to make sure all configuration files for `tailwind CSS` are installed properly or not.

You can follow these steps:

1. > Install Tailwind CSS
   > Install tailwindcss and its peer dependencies via npm, and create your tailwind.config.js file.

(Below command will install all necessary files)

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init
```

2. > Add Tailwind to your PostCSS configuration
   > Add tailwindcss and autoprefixer to your postcss.config.js file, or wherever PostCSS is configured in your project.

(this should be in **postcss.config.js**)

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

3. > Configure your template paths
   > Add the paths to all of your template files in your tailwind.config.js file.

(this should be in **tailwind.config.js**)

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"], //all files paths that you are using
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

4. > Add the Tailwind directives to your CSS
   > Add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind’s layers to your main CSS file.

(change `styles.css` to `index.css` for global styling)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

5. > Start your server using

```
npm run start
```

**Make sure all configurations files are installed properly**

Here's live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/flamboyant-hill-jpe4e2?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A10%2C5)

I hope it helps!